# The C++11 way to build an event loop

Tags: c++, c++11, architecture, event-loop

What's the basic structure of a event loop system in C++11? How are the key elements (such as message queue, message dispatcher, signal) implemented? For example, do I still need a `std::queue<Message>`, a `std::mutex` and a `std::condition_variable` as what I did in *c++98 + boost* way? Also, the performance matters in the solution I'm seeking for.

Comment: There are no high level classes such as message queues in the standard, so you would still have to make your own out of the types you mention.

Comment: If performance matters, stick with mechanisms native to the target OS. For example, use `kqueue` if targeting OS X, or `epoll` for best results on Linux. C++11 has nothing to do with this.

Comment: If you're using Boost already, you could use Boost.Asio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it roughly the same way you would have done it in C++98. You can replace some platform-specific things like pthread_t, pthread_mutex, and pthread_cond with standardized equivalents (std::thread, std::{recursive_,}{timed_,}mutex, and std::condition_variable{,_any}), but the basic design is the same.

As @beerboy mentioned, Boost.Asio might be a good place to start even though AFAIK it hasn't been updated for C++11 yet.